# Mule - Transform XML to SOAP message

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, mule, transform

I receive a `JSON` message to my `mule flow` like this:

```
{
  "book": {
    "author": "Gambardella, Matthew",
    "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
    "genre": "Computer",
    "price": "44.95",
    "publish_date": "2000-10-01",
    "description": "An in-depth look XML"
  }
}
```

And then I use a `JSON to XML transformer` with mule and it returns:

```
   <book >
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look XML</description>
   </book>
```

This is my actual mule flow:

`HTTP` --> `JSON To XML` --> `Logger` --> `WS Consumer`

I want to transform that `XML to SOAP` message adding an **URI** and a **Prefix**.

Why I need a Prefix and a SOAP message? I need it to send to the web service and send as follows:

```
...
    <pref:author>Gambardella, Matthew</pref:author>
...
```

I tried to add an `XSLT component` but it return me an error when I use `:` or `&#x3a;` (Hex code).

I thought to use the `Dataweave (Mapper) component` but it only works with `Mule Enterprise Edition`.

This is the result that I want:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"  xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">
<soap:Body>
   <pref:book>
          <pref:author>Gambardella, Matthew</pref:author>
          <pref:title>XML Developer's Guide</pref:title>
          <pref:genre>Computer</pref:genre>
          <pref:price>44.95</pref:price>
          <pref:publish_date>2000-10-01</pref:publish_date>
          <pref:description>An in-depth look XML</pref:description>
       </pref:book>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What is the best way to do that transformation?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post the exact output you expect to get, including the namespace URI.

Comment: @michael.hor257k sorry, I've just edit the post to explain a bit better

Comment: The post seems clear now. Downvoters, care to remove the downvote? The question helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">
        <soap:Body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="pref:{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your XML example, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">
   <soap:Body>
      <pref:book>
         <pref:author>Gambardella, Matthew</pref:author>
         <pref:title>XML Developer's Guide</pref:title>
         <pref:genre>Computer</pref:genre>
         <pref:price>44.95</pref:price>
         <pref:publish_date>2000-10-01</pref:publish_date>
         <pref:description>An in-depth look XML</pref:description>
      </pref:book>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have used the XSLT component with mule and XSL that you post and it works fine !

Comment: Thanks! Although `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` is often correct